# How can I know the behavior of this non-linear equation as t→∞?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

$ {dx\over dt} = ln(x^2+1) -1 $ as $  t→∞ $

$ x(0)=x_0 $

Comment: The question is unclear.  Perhaps provide some context and what you have tried?

Comment: I tried plotting the vector field for $ X(t) = (^2+1)−1 $, for which I get that the function is increasing after  X= sqrt(e-1)

Comment: Your question is incomplete, you need an initial condition before talking about limiting behavior, since each initial condition could create a new solution, each with wildly different end behaviors.

Comment: My initial condition is an arbitrary X_0

Answer (score 2):

The function $\log(x^2+1)-1$ is Lipschitz in $x$ so we have existence and uniqueness for initial conditions (the derivative $\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$ is bounded by $\pm 1$).

All in all, the differential equation has two equilibrium points (constant solutions) at $x(t)=\pm\sqrt{e-1}$ which also act as asymptotes due to uniqueness, so we have 5 cases:

$$ $$

Case $1$: $\Bigr(x_0 > \sqrt{e-1}\Bigr)$

Here $x'(t)>0$, so the solution will keep increasing forever hence

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)=\infty$$

$$ $$

Case $2$: $\Bigr(x_0 = \sqrt{e-1}\Bigr)$

This is a constant solution with $x'(t)=0$ for all $t$, so

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)=\sqrt{e-1}$$

$$ $$

Case $3$: $\Bigr(-\sqrt{e-1} < x_0 < \sqrt{e-1}\Bigr)$

Plugging into our function we get that $x'(t)<0$ so the solution decreases forever. It is not unbounded, though, as uniqueness prevents it from ever crossing the $x=-\sqrt{e-1}$ line. Therefore we have

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t) = -\sqrt{e-1}$$

$$ $$

Case $4$: $\Bigr(x_0=-\sqrt{e-1}\Bigr)$

Same as the constant solution from before, we get

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t) = -\sqrt{e-1}$$

$$ $$

Case $5$: $\Bigr(x_0 < -\sqrt{e-1}\Bigr)$

Similar to case $1$, since $x'(t)>0$, it will keep increasing forever, but this time it has an upper bound leading us to conclude that

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t) = -\sqrt{e-1}$$

$$ $$

So really we could consolidate the last three cases into one big case for our final answer.

Comment: This is nicely presented.

Comment: How is the derivative bounded by  ±1 if it is a rational function of x?

Comment: @AngellyAquise why does rational preclude it from having bounds?

Comment: @zwim thank you for the kind words!

Comment: I’m confused. Shouldn’t the derivative be constant?

Comment: @AngellyAquise I'm not sure where you got that from, that doesn't make sense. Spend the time to read through the answer, sit with it, and craft a better, more detailed question addressing all of your concerns, in multiple comments if you have to.

Comment: My question is how to verify if the function  $ log(^2+1)−1 $ is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: @AngellyAquise As I said in my answer, its derivative as a function of $x$ is $\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$ which always satisfies the inequality $-1\leq \frac{2x}{x^2+1} \leq 1$. Bounded derivative implies Lipschitz by the mean value theorem.